# JavaFX fire close tab event

Tags: javafx

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                e.consume();
                if (currentEditor.isModified()){
                    switch (DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText())){
                        case "Yes": tabPane.fireEvent(???);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I would like to make a confirmation for a tabbed text editor, where there are opetions "yes" "no" cancel". Is there a way to fire a close tab event when "yes" is selected? thanks

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                if (currentEditor.isModified()){
                    switch (DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText())){
                        case "Yes":
                            saveFile();
                        case "Cancel":
                            e.consume();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Sadly, when `currentEditor.isModified()` is `false`, the tab can't be closed, any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Find the one you need. http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/. I am guessing you need a Confirmation Dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consuming the event vetoes the close. So you should only consume the event if the user decides they do not want to close the tab. Otherwise, let the event propagate, and the tab will close:

```
tab.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
    // remove the next line: you only want to consume the event for "No"
    // e.consume();
    if (currentEditor.isModified()){
        if ("No".equals(DialogBox.newSaveConfirmationBox(tab.getText()))) {
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```